# Delete the author of figure in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I want to put the author of the image but I do not want the author to appear in the Table of Contents, how do I delete it from the table of contents to the author?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{example-image}
            \caption{Proceso (Akarwal:2008)}
            \label{procesoClasificacionDatos} 

        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to achieve this is to use the optional argument for `\caption[<LoF>]{<caption>}`, so use

```
\caption[Proceso]{Proceso (Akarwal:2008)}
```